# Why kafka consumer (0.10.0.0) for new consumer group does see old/previously published messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a producer that publishes messages on a topic called 'mytopic' just fine. I have 2 consumers in 2 different consumer groups listening for these messages. I started these 2 consumers and producer in following sequence.

1) Start consumer 1 in group 'group1'
2) start producer to publish several hundreds messages

After sometime I check the offset of consumer 1, which is as I expect:

`/opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0/bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic mytopic --group group1`

Output:

`Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
group1           mytopic                         0   30230           36942           6712            none`

3) Now I start consumer 2 in group 'group2' to listen to the same messages but it comes back with 0 messages on every poll() call.
The offset check for this consumer shows me that its offset is same as the logSize.

`/opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0/bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic mytopic --group group2`

Output:
`Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner
group2           mytopic                         0   36942           36942           0               none`

Same problem for any other consumer with a new consumer group. Why is the consumer joining a new consumer group after messages have been published not seeing the old messages even though messages exists on the topic (ie., haven't been deleted)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change parameter setting `auto.offset.reset` to value `"earliest"` in you consumer configuration -- default value is `"latest"` telling a new consumer to start consuming at the current end of the log.